# Failed Assertion: Boolean expression must not be null

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I stored `isQuick` value from the backend. I used sqflite to cache.
Always result is `false`

**In my dashboard page,**

```
 bool isQuick;
 @override
  void initState() {
 isQuick = false;

 timer1 = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) {
  checkQuick(_url, tokens, isQuick);
});

timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (Timer t) {
      Future datas = HelperDatabase1().displayGetUserPreference();
      datas.then((v) => {
        data = v,
        print('new data ${data[0].data}'),
        data[0].data == 0 ? this.isQuick == false : this.isQuick == true,
        print(this.isQuick)
      });
      submitRequestSave(_url, tokens);
    });
    }
```

**in my build method,**

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async => false,
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          appBar: AssetRegisterAppBar(context),
          body: makeBody(litems, litems_icon, _url, this.isQuick, isOffline,
              statusbarHeight, context),
        ));
}
```

**checkQuick method,**

```
  Future checkQuick(String url, String token, bool isQuick) async {
    print('quick $isQuick');
    bool newQuick;
    final response = await http.get(
      '$url/nativeapi/v1.0/User/GetUserPreference',
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'},
    );
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    GetUserPreference model = GetUserPreference.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    var data = GetUserPreference(data: model.data);
    print(data.data);
    if (data.data == 0) {
      newQuick = false;
    } else {
      newQuick = true;
    }
    print('new quick $newQuick');
    if (isQuick != newQuick) {
      int newData;
      if (newQuick) {
        newData = 1;
      } else {
        newData = 0;
      }
      await HelperDatabase1().updateGetUserPreference(1, newData);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your isQuick was `null` at the time it was called to build your page. Assign a default value to it:

```
@override
void initState() {
  isQuick = false; // or true

  Future datas = HelperDatabase1().displayGetUserPreference();
  datas.then((v) =>
    {data = v, data[0].data == 0 ? this.isQuick == false : this.isQuick == true});
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

To address the main issue, you need to display the alternative widgets (such as `CircularProgressIndicator`) when the value of `isQuick` is still loading (or is still `null`).

```
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async => false,
  child: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    appBar: AssetRegisterAppBar(context),
    body: isQuick == null
      ? CircularProgressIndicator()
      : makeBody(litems, litems_icon, _url, this.isQuick, isOffline, statusbarHeight, context),
  ),
);
```

Comment: My cache value `isQuick` is true. Is it changing?

Comment: You still need to supply a default value while the actual value is being loaded from the backend. A good practice is normally to display a loading screen until all necessary data is loaded from the backend.

Comment: How to do it? I need to call to thr backend every 10 second abd check `isquick` value change or not..If change I need to update my local database

Comment: I added to your method. not working. I modified my questioon also